# Tesseract OCR using tess4j library

Tags: java, ocr

Tesseract not recognizing text properly. I am using the tess4j library and I am getting around 50% accuracy. I have a tiff file with very small fonts size. How can I improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the image to get a better recognition, see https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality .